# Raphael.js - scale an element over time

Tags: raphael

Very new to using Raphael.js

I'm looking at the tutorials and I am able to create a circle.

But how would I scale the circle to double the size over two seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your circle is created like:

`var circle = paper.circle(50, 40, 10);`

You can scale it up over two seconds like:

```
circle.animate({
    transform: 's2'
}, 2000, 'easeIn');
```

You could also just double its radius if it is fixed.