# Zoom n the partcular country n raphael.js

Tags: raphael

1. . I am very new to raphael.js.I have done a europe map using t.I'm
           able    to change color while mouseover.But I just want to zoom the 
           particular country while t s clicked.It must be like zoom t the
           clicked country with some specific points n the country

   ```
       script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
              $(document).ready(function() {
               var rsr = Raphael('map', '631', '686');
               var attr = {
                          fill: "#C0C0C0",
                          stroke: "#666",
                          "stroke-width": 1,
                          "stroke-linejoin": "round"
                      };
                  var world = {};
                  world.Portugal = rsr.path("56,0.133-1.32,0.527c-0.661,1.321-0.264,2.906-0.925,4.228c-0.528,1.057-3.698,5.415-3.434,6.868
   c0.132,0.526,1.056-0.529,1.584-0.529c0.792-0.132,1.585,0.133,2.377,0c0.396,0,0.792-0.396,1.188-0.264
   c2.113,0.527,8.981,5.019,9.906,4.887c0.396,0,4.49-1.981,4.754-2.113C57.876,621.536,58.537,621.536,59.197,621.536L59.197,621.536
   z").attr(attr);;
                  world.Spain = rsr.path(" M194.57,552.728c0.924,0.396,1.981,0.63.434,4.754c-,0,0.792,0    
   c0.661,0.133,1.453,0.133,1.849,0.528c0.66,0.528,0.264,1.717,0.924,2.113v0.132C190.74,552.066,190.476,553.916,194.57,552.728
   L194.57,552.728z").attr(attr);
          var current = null;
                   for(var country in world) {
                    (function (st, country) {
                      country = country.toLowerCase();
                        st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
                        st[0].onmouseover = function () { 
                            st.animate({fill:"#808080", stroke: "#ccc"}, 500);
                        };
                        st[0].onmouseout = function () {
                            st.animate({fill: "#C0C0C0", stroke: "#666"}, 500);
                            st.toFront();
                            R.safari();
                        };
                        st[0].onclick = function () {
                         st.animate({width: "500px"}, 'slow');//THS DOES NOT WORk
                        };
                    })(world[country], country);
                  }
                });
   ```

   can anyone help me how to do ths???please

   ```
   ..
   ```

Comment: Please reformat your question - it's impossible to read in its current state

Comment: I suggest you make a http://jsfiddle.net/ of it or, failing that, describe what behavior you are trying to achieve, how you do that and what is going wrong.

Comment: @boz it is readable, actually, just very unpleasant to read. And the answer is that OP is trying to set the 'width' attribute which the path, in fact, does not possess. The correct way to go is to set the 'transform' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set the 'width' attribute which the path, in fact, does not possess. The way to go is to set the 'transform' attribute as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9866684/raphael-js-scale-an-element-over-time?rq=1). You might also have to set the scaling origin, since the path you are scaling is not centered at zero (cf. [Raphael center of scale in transform method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867975/raphael-center-of-scale-in-transform-method)).

Comment: Many Thans for your reply.How should I use transform n the map.Please explain me snce I'm very new to raphaeel.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9867975/raphael-center-of-scale-in-transform-method, there's an example.

Comment: Thans a lot Qnan for ur effort.But tried that like  st[0].onclick = function () {
                   st.transform("s0.500")
                  }; It doesnot work..

Comment: Try st.animate({transform: "s0.5"}, 'slow');

Comment: I dont know y t does not work for me..Do we need to nclude any js apart from raphael.js?